# switch between branches, preserving the stash?

Tags: git, git-stash, git-checkout

Sometimes I could use an equivalent of `git stash && git checkout $branch && git stash pop` that would remember what was the state of the tree for a given branch and only restore the one that was stashed for this particular branch. How could easily achieve that?

Answer (score 1):

You can also use `stash-and-checkout` command of [git-whistles](https://github.com/mezis/git-whistles). Git-whistles is a Ruby gem, so if you have Ruby installed, you can install git-whistles with `gem install git-whistles`. Then you can simply do `git stash-and-checkout [branch]` to achieve what you're wanting to do.

For brevity I've defined a shell alias `g` for git, and git alias `co` for `stash-and-checkout`, so to stash any uncommitted work on the current branch, switch to the new branch, and pop that branch's stash (if any), I can simply type `g co [branch]`. For git alias setup example see my *.gitconfig* at [github.com/vwal/my-git-extras](https://github.com/vwal/my-git-extras).

Answer (score 0):

By design, `git stash` makes a temporary commit<sup>1</sup> that is not on *any* branch.  This is so that you can apply it anywhere else.

If you want to save the state of the index and/or work-tree and associate that state with a particular branch, what Git provides that does this is `git commit`.  Really, that's all you need: a regular old commit.<sup>2</sup>  You can "uncommit" later, once you come back to that branch, with `git reset --soft HEAD^`.

If you want to wrap this up into one package, you could choose a short commit message that you promise never to use in a "real" commit, and write a little wrapper for `git checkout` (note, this is quite untested):

```
#! /bin/sh
# git-swapto: commit any temporary work, swap to another branch;
# automatically de-commits temporary work.

# for git-sh-setup: can work in subdirectory
SUBDIRECTORY_OK=true
. $(git --exec-path)/git-sh-setup

case $# in
1) ;;
*) die "usage: git-swapto <branch>";;
esac

require_work_tree

# From require_clean_work_tree, converted to status;
# assumes work tree exists.
work_tree_is_clean() {
    git update-index -q --ignore-submodules --refresh
    # if diff-files says different, fail (work tree not clean)
    git diff-files --quiet --ignore-submodules || return 1
    # if diff-index says index is different, fail (index not clean)
    git diff-index --cached --quiet --ignore-submodules HEAD || return 1
    # both work tree and index are clean => nothing to commit
    return 0
}

# Force branch name as argument, since we want to do a soft
# reset if there is a temporary commit on it.  Also, require
# that current HEAD name a branch.
case "$(git rev-parse --symbolic-full-name "$1")" in
refs/heads/*) ;;
*) die "`$1': not a branch name";;
esac
git symbolic-ref -q HEAD >/dev/null || die "not currently on a branch"

temp_commit_string="!! temporary commit, do not push"
# test whether HEAD refers to our temporary commit
current_commit_is_temp() {
    local head_text="$(git log --no-walk --pretty=format:%B)"
    test "$head_text" = "$temp_commit_string"
}

# Before leaving this branch, make a temporary commit if
# necessary, amending existing temporary commit if there is one.
# (We should never need --amend, this is just paranoia.)
if ! work_tree_is_clean; then
    echo "note: leaving temp commit behind" 1>&2
    if current_commit_is_temp; then
        git commit -a --amend --no-edit ||
            die "cannot update current temp commit"
    else
        git commit -a -m "$temp_commit_string" --no-edit ||
            die "cannot make temp commit"
    fi
fi

# work tree is now clean, switch to target
git checkout "$1" || die "cannot switch to $1"

# finally, if it is our special temp commit, reset it away
if current_commit_is_temp; then
    git reset --soft HEAD^ || die "failed to unmake temp commit"
fi
# all done, for good or ill...
```

---

<sup>1</sup>Actually it makes at least two, and sometimes three, temporary commits.  This is more "mechanism" than "policy" though, while "not on a branch" is policy/design.

<sup>2</sup>Or, as with `git stash`, use *two* commits if you want to preserve "index" and "work-tree" separately.  Otherwise just add stuff to the index as usual, then make a single commit.